# Question about dimension of affine variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ versus over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have polynomials $F_1, ..., F_r \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, ..., x_t]$.
Then the zero set of these polynomials define an affine variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ and over $\mathbb{C}$. Are these two dimensions always the same or is it possible that they are different? Thank you very much!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by an affine variety over $\mathbb{Q}$, and by the dimension of such a thing. There are sophisticated definitions that make the answer yes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you possibly elaborate a little more on what the sophisticated definition is? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $x_1^2+\cdots+x_t^2$ defines a single point over $\Bbb Q$ and a hypersurface over $\Bbb C$.

Also see $x^n+y^n-1$ in relation with Fermat's last theorem.